# Amazon Cognito developer authenticated identity with Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to authenticate a java app to AWS services using a developer-authenticated Cognito identity.  This is very straightforward in the AWS mobile SDKs ([documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html%20/documentation)), but I can't seem to find the equivalent classes in the Java SDK.

The main issue I am having is that the Java SDK classes (such as WebIdentityFederationSessionCredentialsProvider) require the client code to know the arn of the role being assumed.  With the mobile SDK, it uses the role configured for the federated identity.  That's what I'd prefer to do, but it seems the Java SDK doesn't have the supporting classes for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last comment from Jeff led me to the answer.  Thanks Jeff!

```
String cognitoIdentityId = "your user's identity id";
String openIdToken = "open id token for the user created on backend";

Map<String,String> logins = new HashMap<>();
logins.put("cognito-identity.amazonaws.com", openIdToken);
GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest getCredentialsRequest =
    new GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest()
    .withIdentityId(cognitoIdentityId)
    .withLogins(logins);
AmazonCognitoIdentityClient cognitoIdentityClient = new AmazonCognitoIdentityClient();
GetCredentialsForIdentityResult getCredentialsResult = cognitoIdentityClient.getCredentialsForIdentity(getCredentialsRequest);
Credentials credentials = getCredentialsResult.getCredentials();
AWSSessionCredentials sessionCredentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(
    credentials.getAccessKeyId(),
    credentials.getSecretKey(),
    credentials.getSessionToken()
);

AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(sessionCredentials);
...
```

Comment: This link was helpful -> https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2323YHCM0I7OO/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-4-Enhanced-Flow

Answer (score 0):

If that's the route you want to go, you can find this role in the IAM console, named Cognito_(Auth|Unauth)_DefaultRole. These are what Cognito generated and linked to your pool, and you can get the ARN from there.

[This blog post](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxBVEDL5Z8JKAC/Use-Amazon-Cognito-in-your-website-for-simple-AWS-authentication) may be of some assistance. All of the APIs the SDK uses to communicate with Cognito to get credentials are exposed in the Java SDK, you just need to use your own back end to get the token itself. Once you have it, you can set the logins the same way you normally would with another provider and it'll all work.

Comment: Sorry, that blog post doesn't help.  It uses AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity,which requires that you know ahead of time the ARN of the role.  I understand you can get that ARN through the AWS console, but I need to programmatically determine it without the java client having direct access to the AWS account (the java client does not have access keys for AWS).  The backend does supply the access token needed to authenticated.

Comment: Can you clarify why you need to determine it programmatically? The console ones are exactly what the service does in the mobile SDK, so if that's what you'd prefer to do it would make that possible. What the client SDKs did before the simplified flow was introduced was have the dev input strings and select based on login status, which is what you could do. In any case, the blog was largely to show how to use everything other than the credentials provider.

Comment: In my case, the client app only knows 4 things:the AWS account id, the identity pool id, the id of the user's identity in that pool, and an OpenId token for that identity.  With those 4 things I can authenticate the user in the mobile SDK, but I can't seem to find a way to do the same in the Java SDK.  In the JavaSDK, I also need the ARN of the role to be assumed by the Cognito identity.

Comment: Right, that's why I suggested that. Sorry, I'm still not clear on why you can't put the role arn from the IAM console inside the code? That's what the mobile SDK did up until recently.

Comment: Because the ARN will vary based on who logs into the app.  Users are potentially in different identity pools

Comment: Oh multiple pools. Understood. There isn't a publicly exposed mapping of roles to pool from Cognito, so my best suggestion would be to keep track of a mapping of your own somewhere and communicate with that.

Comment: I'm curious how the mobile SDKs accomplish this then?  An undocumented end point?

Comment: Before the enhanced authentication was introduced, the developer had to input the role arns manually. Those constructors are still available, if you're curious. With pools created since that feature launched, cognito keeps a mapping in the background that it reads from. This applies in the GetCredentialsForIdentity API, the server pulls this role out. The mobile SDK does no part of it anymore.