# Amazon Cognito developer authenticated identity with iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

What I would like to achieve it as in follow link: [Amazon Cognito developer authenticated identity with Java SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441696/amazon-cognito-developer-authenticated-identity-with-java-sdk)
But it is for java sdk for aws cognito. As for iOS, I have identity ID and openIdToken. 
I would love to know how I can pass the openIdToekn in swift using the iOS sdk for aws cognito.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the link mentioned here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html to implement your use case. It is under the section iOS - Objective-C.

Comment: I got a way to retrieve credentials, but the doc doesn't mention about it. I will update the question at weekend. And one more thing, is there any source describing about manually adding received credentials to call api? I may need to implement iOS sdk generated from API gateway and in the docs, there is no mention of credentials. I am in a rush, so it needed I will make separate post.